# knife search for nested attribute

Tags: automation, chef-infra, knife

I want to search for a node using knife search command for a node which has override attributes in node file.

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
knife search node "datadog.agent_version::5.4.3-1"
```

This is how I have the override specified in the node file

```
    "datadog": {
      "agent_version": "5.4.3-1"
    },
```

Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: https://docs.chef.io/knife_search.html#nested-fields

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work `knife search node "datadog_agent_version:5.4.3-1"`. This functionality is fully [documented](https://docs.chef.io/knife_search.html).

Comment: this return me all nodes, because i am overriding agent_version attribute in role file as well. But here I want to search for nodes for which I have set agent_version attributes in node files if any.

Comment: so you can go with just `"agent_version:*"` pattern if you don't need exact hierarchy structure.

Comment: I tired this knife search node "agent_version:*" -a "Node Name" but its still returning all nodes. i want only list of nodes for which node file has override

Comment: Let's take a step back. If you search for a node - it already contains all overrides after bootstrapping/converging. in query above I would use just `-a name`. If you don't have any result just try to run `knife client list` to see if machine you are looking for is in general available.

Comment: yes node is available in `knife client list`. so to test this i override "agent_version:" in node file in one of the node but same override is present in role file also, but here I want to search that specific node for which override is set into node file.

Comment: ok, so it should be smth like `knife search node -a "agent_version:*" -a "override:agent_version:5.4.3-1"` if agent_version attribute is in override level. @roy

Answer (score 0):

Have you run chef-client after changing attributes?
I believe new attributes appear only after successful chef-client run.